# Custom Number Format for Number Range in Cell

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting

I have a cell that contains a number range, say `50-60` that I would like to apply custom number formatting to. Ideally, I'd like to be able to format that to output `50Hz-60Hz`.

The syntax that works for a regular integer is `#"Hz"`, but I can't find an in-built way to do this for dashed ranges, and I suspect it isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the number format cannot be used for this situation because `50-60` is a text. So I proposed to process it as the text as a workaround. But from your replying, I could understand that my answer was not useful. So I have to delete my answer, because I don't want to confuse other users. I apologize for this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*As you suspected, this isn't possible to do.*

#### More Information:

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) has said in his above comment, the cell input `50-60` is a string - purely read as text as it contains the `-` character. Resultantly, Sheets does not have the functionality to use Number formatting to change the way this is displayed.

#### (Kind of) Workarounds:

***Disclaimer:*** *These suggestions are not perfect workarounds and depending on how the data in the cells is processed elsewhere in the sheet, these may not work. They do however provide solutions if you are looking to affect the UI only.*

**Workaround 1: Using a custom Number Format**

You can use the format `##"Hz-"##"Hz"` which will display `50Hz-60Hz` for the example you give, if the input of the cell is `5060` rather than `50-60`. You will however need to change the format to contain three `#` characters if the frequency range of the cell goes above 100:

- `##"Hz-"##"Hz"` will make the number `5060` display as `50Hz-60Hz`
- `###"Hz-"###"Hz"` will make the number `120130` display as `120Hz-130Hz`
- `####"Hz-"####"Hz"` will make the number `14201430` display as `1420Hz-1430Hz`

**Workaround 2: Using an `onEdit(e)` Trigger**

If inputting the `-` yourself is important, then you can use an `onEdit()` Apps Script trigger to change the format of the cell to include the `Hz` unit after-the-fact.

For this workaround, I will assume that the column your frequency ranges are in is column C.

From the `Tools > Script editor` menu item, you can create a function with the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() != 3) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    var f = e.value.split("-");
    e.range.setValue(f = f[0] + "Hz-" + f[1] + "Hz");
  }
}
```

Make sure to change the value on the line `if (e.range.getColumn() != 3)` to be whichever column your frequency ranges are: this example uses the value 3 because the column is assumed to be column C, but column D would be 4, E would be 5, etc.

Save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

This will automatically run whenever a value like `50-60` is inputted into column C, and will change to display `50Hz-60Hz` instead.

**Workaround 3: Using a Custom Function**

Google Sheets allow you to write custom formulae that work in a similar way to the built in formulae like `=SUM()` or `=COUNT()`.

Following the same steps as in workaround 2 to open the Script editor, create the following function:

```js
function hertzify(f) {
  f = f.split("-");
  return f[0] + "Hz-" + f[1] + "Hz";
}
```

This does a similar thing as workaround 2, but instead of automatically changing the values of whatever is in a specific column, you call the function by entering the following formula in a cell:

```
=HERTZIFY("50-60")
```

This will change the cell's display value to `50Hz-60Hz` like before.

You can also use this on other cells; for example if cell `C3` has the text `120-130` and in cell `D3` you input `=HERTZIFY(C3)`, then `D3` will display `120Hz-130Hz`.

#### Feature Request:

As the above workarounds either process the cell data as if they are text or require the number to be formatted in a specific way, they might not be perfect workarounds for all situations.

In this case I suggest filing a feature request with Google for the ability to define a number format for a range of values in a specific cell.

You can do this by either following the `Help > Report a problem` menu item from the Google Sheets user interface, or make a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker asking to implement this as a feature. The link to the Issue Tracker is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com)

#### References:

- [Format numbers in a spreadsheet - Computer - Doc Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)